# Скрытие системных запросов Windows в приложении Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qtcreator

Программа со скрытым главным окном (`MainWindow->hide()`) осуществляет системные запросы через `system("")` (например, `ping 192.168.0.1`) и отталкивается в своих действиях от возвращаемых значений. Проблема в том, что каждый вызов `system` открывает на момент времени окно командной строки, что идет вразрез с задачей программы-демона (фонового процесса).
Как можно скрыть системные вызовы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Вас нет "системных вызовов". Вы просто запускаете приложение в консоли и соответственно видите все. Хотите больше гибкости и контроля - используйте правильные инструменты, к примеру, [QProcess](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html)

[Где то так](https://forum.qt.io/topic/62393/how-to-use-qtprocess-with-ping-command/5):

```
QString hostName = "127.0.0.1";
QProcess* proc = new QProcess();
proc->start("ping", QStringList() << "-c" << "3" << QString(hostName));
```

Comment: Спасибо за дельный ответ! Может быть навскидку сможете сказать, как мне получить валидный код завершения (`return proc.exitStatus();`), т.к. при `proc.close()` он всегда ненулевой, а при `proc.waitForFinish` - всегда нулевой. А мне необходимо знать пингуется ли заданный узел, или нет.

Comment: Вы сами пишите "код", а функцию вызываете "статус":) exitStatus возвращает только процесс сам завершился или ему помогли (и то не всегда). Вам нужен exitCode при условии, что exitStatus == 0 (если процесс крашнулся, то он не может возвратить ничего, кроме своего дампа)

Comment: действительно, я перегрелся. Статусом пытаюсь себе код вернуть... Однако:
`proc.start("ping", QStringList() << "192.168.0.1 -n 1"); \n
    proc.waitForFinished(); \n
    return proc.exitCode();`
Постоянно ненулевое значение возвращает... Хотя должен вроде бы и нолик иногда отдавать :)

Comment: а может и не должен. тут все очень сильно зависит от ОС и других обстоятельств.

Comment: что интересное заметил: при пинге несуществующей подсети (например, 192.168.8.1) возвращается валидная ошибка, а при пинге существующей подсети, но отсутствующего в нем узла - ошибки нет, возвращается ноль. В целом, этого для моей задачи достаточно. Большое спасибо за помощь!